# Disable all function keys except F2

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard

I want to use ***function key `F2` (edit cell) only*** and Disable all other function keys..

What is the ***vba code for enabling function key `F2` only and disabling all other function keys?*** and return to default upon exiting workbook..

Should it be written inside *`thisWorkbook`* or some modules.. if there is same name for this code inside *`thisWorkbook`* - how should it be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I use would use a 3rd party command-line app like [**Autohotkey**](https://autohotkey.com/).  Just call it from VBA with the `Shell` command.

- Here's a example AHK script: [**"No More <kbd>Fn</kbd> Keys"**](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/112730-no-more-fn-key/).
- Here's docs on the **VBA [`Shell` Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function)**.